# Why Do We Need Initial Conditions to Solve PDEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, motivation

I am looking for further clarity on why solving PDEs without any specified initial values was not "good enough." For example: say we had the ODE
\begin{equation}
y' = y
\end{equation}
without specifying any initial conditions. Solving it, we get:
$$
y(x) = Ce^x.
$$
Doesn't this tell give us an explicit description of the solutions to $\textit{every}$ initial value problem posed with the above ODE? Doesn't the end product of $\textit{specifically}$ solving the initial value problem give us less information than solving the PDE generally? If so, why do we care so much about IVPs? Why not always solve PDEs first and then think about "Oh I wonder what would happen if it started here..."?

Comment: Because explicitly finding a general solution (with free constant) is rare even for ODEs. For PDEs a general  solution will have a free function and that is even more rare in explicit form. So "solve PDEs first" replaces a simpler problem with a harder problem, which is often intractable. Characteristics of the solution may change dramatically as the free constant, let alone the free function, varies, and without explicit form it is very hard to track that, if at all possible. In applications we often just need to solve IVP, which can be done numerically, for general solution that won't work.

Comment: Some can have a big space of solutions, often infinitely big in different senses. It is why we need not only initial conditions but also often regularization.